# Unknown gridlines on old Greenland base map!

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

Can anyone help me out please?

I'm using an old 1:10,000 base map of Greenland for a mapping project with nice 10cm gridlines already drawn on. However it uses a coordinate system which is unfamiliar to me, it has values of 92 up to 112 on y axis and 124 to 138 on x axis, which increase by increments of 2. My mapping area is around 61 N, 45.15 W, can anyone please tell me what the grid system my map uses represents?

Thanks 
Eleni

Comment: Can you tell us who made that map?

Comment: If you have any additional information about the extent of the map, who produced it, and when it was made, that would be useful information to answer your question.

Comment: The map is Qalilingmiut qàqâ - Nuluk, South Greenland and it was produced by Geodœtisk Institut, Denmark

Comment: The copy I have is about 30 years old now and the section we have covers about 64km^2

Comment: It might be (or a variation) of Qornoq 1927 / Greenland zone 8 East, EPSG:2307, but EPSG says the axes are positive north and west. http://www.epsg-registry.org